# Python3 Quart register_blueprint of python-healthz throws exception

Tags: python-3.x, flask, http2, kubernetes-health-check, quart

I use `flask` and trying to migrate to `quart` in order to benefit from HTTP/2. I use `flask-healthz` for kubernetes readiness and liveness health checks. Is there any `quart` equivalent of `flask-healthz`?

I am not sure it would work but trying to `register_blueprint(healthz, url_prefix="/health")` throws the following exception:

```
  File "/app/src/app.py", line 37, in create_app
    app.register_blueprint(healthz, url_prefix="/healthz")
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/quart/app.py", line 507, in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 322, in register
    state = self.make_setup_state(app, options, first_registration)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 250, in make_setup_state
    return BlueprintSetupState(self, app, options, first_registration)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.url_defaults.update(self.options.get("url_defaults", ()))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart/-/issues/437#

Comment: You need to add a little more information. What were you doing, how? We don't know your application code, so it's hard to guess what went wrong? What version of kubernetes are you using? What exactly do you want to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the following fixes:
(1) `import quart.flask_patch`
(2) Change the `scheme` of the health check endpoint to `HTTPS`